# using rvest to scrape data from a long table with pagination

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to data scraping and trying to use rvest to scrape all the salary data from the long table on this website:
https://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/

as expected, the following code gives me the variable names of the data:

```
url <- "https://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/"
names <- url %>% 
read_html() %>%
html_node('thead') %>%
html_text()
```

However, why this code gives me no data?

```
url <- "https://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/"
dat <- url %>% 
read_html() %>%
html_node('tbody') %>%
html_text()
```

I followed an example in this article: http://bradleyboehmke.github.io/2015/12/scraping-html-tables.html

```
url <- "https://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/"
sal <- url %>% 
read_html() %>%
html_node('#table-example') %>%
html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

Again, it produces only column names with no data.

Also, how should I read through all the tens of thousands of pages to get all the data from the table? I suspect that I need to use the information in "#table-example_wrapper > div:nth-child(2) > div", but don't know how.  Could anyone help?

Comment: I cannot help. I only realise your pagination is perhaps run by java(?)script and needs an approach that involves pretending the link is clicked. Selenium (RSelenium) is capable of this. Maybe you can add a label RSelenium and Selenium to your question.